# Template for callback in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm designing a class to receive a callback in c++. Until now this is my code:

```
template <class T, typename K = void, typename P = void> 
class Callback {
private:
  typedef K (T::*Callback)(P*);
  Callback c;
  T* ptr;
  P* data;
public:
  Callback(T* _thisPtr, Callback _funcPtr, P* pp) { ptr = _thisPtr;  c = _funcPtr; data = pp; };
  virtual void execute() { (ptr->*c)(data); };
};
```

This code works but now I want a bit more flexibility. As you can see this works for a method defined with at least one parameter of type P*. I'd like to have a class to manage a variable list of arguments. A constraint here is that I can't use C++11 because I have to use gcc 4.4, any tips?

Comment: Did you check `boost::function` ?

Comment: @quantdev I'd prefer avoid to use external libraries like boost if possible

Comment: @greywolf82 That's too bad because most of boost is header only, and stuff like `boost::function` (only headers) is, as you noticed, really hard to get right.

Comment: You can bind multiple arguments into a struct and pass the address of this struct. One downside is, it would be perform slower for primitive types.

Comment: @quantdev Maybe I could use tr1 instead of pure c++11, but however if I use std::tr1::function I don't know how to apply it in my code

Answer (score 4):

Building a general purpose, polymorphic, fast, safe, generic function wrapper, is not an easy task.

For that reason, if C++11 [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is unavailable, I would go for [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/function.html).

It is header-only, and has a very good documentation. Plus it will be easy to switch to `std::function` once it will be available to you.

Really, it will save you days of debugging. You can see on SO with the amount of questions related to *"I have a bug in my `Callback` class, why ?"* (See the "related" section on the right ... )

Comment: Myabe I just realized that what I want to do it's not possible. Why? Because in my design I have to store the parameters in the class and use them in the execute() method. I can't store a variable list to pass back it to the function.

Comment: @greywolf82 you can do that with `boost::bind`, or just write a simple wrapper around the function + your args